# Publishing EAR containing Spring Rest Service in WebLogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c, ear

I've built a small project to provide rest services using springframework. the problem is to access this project inside an EAR after publishing this EAR into a WebLogic server.

When I publish this project as an standalone war in my weblogic everything ends well, my SpringWebAppInitializer is loaded as expected when the server starts and I can reach the webservice using the address localhost:7001/internal-webservices/project/12. But when I add this WAR to the EAR, the SpringWebAppInitializer is never invoked.

Any ideas?

Some of my configurations:

The pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

My ApplicationContextConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("my_package.*")
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
// No need ViewSolver
// Other declarations if needed ...      
}
```

My WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("internal-webservices",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // UTF8 Charactor Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

}
```

And, my RestController class:

```
@RestController
public class ProjectController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/project/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
 produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public List<String> getProject(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add("id: "+ id);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Regards,
Felipe

Comment: did you find out what was wrong?